# SOAPUI java illegalstateexception scheme 'https' not registered

Tags: java, soap, soapui

I am trying to test connection to webservice using the soap UI. Created the project by importing the WSDL into soapUI and also set the keystore and keystore password under SSL seetings.

However when I submit the request I get below error. Not sure how to register "https". Can you please help?

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Scheme 'https' not registered
```

Comment: Are you using default https port? What version of soapui are you using?

Comment: Yes, I am using the defualt port. Not setting it specifically anywhere. I am using SoapUI 5.0.0.

Comment: I give you a possible solution as an answer... however I'm not sure that this can work, just try it :).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to create a groovy testStep in your testCase with the code below, this code creates the SSLContext and registry the https scheme... however I'm not sure that this can works in your environment because some times the `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Scheme 'https' not registered` is an issue in the network (could be you are behind a proxy etc.). Hope this helps.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLContext;
import javax.net.ssl.TrustManager;
import javax.net.ssl.X509TrustManager;
import java.security.cert.CertificateException;
import java.security.cert.X509Certificate;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.ResponseHandler;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.conn.ClientConnectionManager;
import org.apache.http.conn.scheme.Scheme;
import org.apache.http.conn.scheme.SchemeRegistry;
import org.apache.http.conn.scheme.SchemeSocketFactory;
import org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.BasicResponseHandler;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.ClientParamsStack;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.params.DefaultedHttpParams;
import org.apache.http.params.HttpParams;
import org.apache.http.entity.InputStreamEntity;
import java.security.SecureRandom;
import java.security.KeyStore;
import javax.net.ssl.KeyManager;
import javax.net.ssl.KeyManagerFactory;
import javax.net.ssl.TrustManagerFactory;


HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

// init SSL

// load your keystore
KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("jks"); 
keyStore.load(new FileInputStream("path_to_your_keystore"), "your_keystore_password".toCharArray());
// create keystore manager
KeyManagerFactory keyManagerFactory = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance("SunX509");
keyManagerFactory.init(keyStore, password.toCharArray());

// load your truststore
KeyStore trustStore = KeyStore.getInstance("jks");
trustStore.load(new FileInputStream("path_to_your_truststore"), "your_trustore_password".toCharArray());
// create truststore manager
TrustManagerFactory trustManagerFactory = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance("SunX509");
trustManagerFactory.init(trustStore);

// create the ssl context
SSLContext context = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
context.init(keyManagerFactory.getKeyManagers(), trustManagerFactory.getTrustManagers(), new SecureRandom());
SSLSocketFactory ssf = new SSLSocketFactory(ctx);

//register https protocol in httpclient's scheme registry
ClientConnectionManager ccm = httpclient.getConnectionManager();
SchemeRegistry sr = ccm.getSchemeRegistry();
sr.register(new Scheme("https", 443, ssf));

// create the request
HttpPost post = new HttpPost("https://your_service_endpoint_url")
def bais = new ByteArrayInputStream("<SOAP:Envelope>...your_xml</SOAP:Envelope>".getBytes("UTF-8"))
def reqEntity = new InputStreamEntity(bais, bais.available());
reqEntity.setContentType("application/xml");
post.setEntity(reqEntity);

// make the post and get the response
ResponseHandler responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
def responseBody = httpclient.execute(post, responseHandler);
log.info responseBody;
```

Alternatively you can use `SOAPUI 5.1.3` version, which seems that doesn't have this problem.

Comment: Yes, it ended being firewall. Needed to go through intermediate server. Thanks for the answer and also code snippet looks good for someone who wants to run a qucick test.

Comment: @albciff I have the same problem, sure not caused by firewall, but I don't know "groovy testStep", I just have a soap message, how to register https in soap UI?

Comment: @user1169587 what do you mean by "I don't know groovy testStep"? I don't know if you're asking this, however you can add to your testCase a special testStep called `groovy` and inside this testStep you can add the code from the answer.

Comment: @albciff After I upgrade the soapUI to 5.1.3, no this problem now.