# Scheme 'https' not registered

Tags: https, soapui

I use soapUI 4.5.2 on windows 7, my endpoint url is https prefix (protocol), but soapUI always return

"Scheme 'https' not registered"

how to register https in soapUI?

I have already set Keystore and Keystore password property in soapUI preference. And the problem is sure not come from firewall.

Comment: possible duplicate of [SOAPUI java illegalstateexception scheme 'https' not registered](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23915388/soapui-java-illegalstateexception-scheme-https-not-registered)

Answer (score 0):

After upgrade to soapUI 5.1.3, no this error now. (Scheme 'https' not registered), can use https in endpoint.